# Django 1.6 trying to create new database entry from form

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to develop a thank-you note system using Django. I have set up admin ok and am able to add new entries to the database through that. I have also been able to set up index  which shows all current thank-you notes in database, and also a detail view which shows the full details for a given thank-you note. I am trying to create a form view that lets people without admin access add thank-you notes to the system. The form loads fine and the fields can be filled but everytime I press submit I get a 404 error. The only way this doesn't happen is if I set the form action nothing:

```
<form id=“new_ty_form” method=“post” action=>
```

and pressing submit with this just regenerates a blank form and does nothing with the previous fields.

I am also completely unable to implement the {% url %} system which means that I have to hardcode all urls I am using. Whenever I try to use {% url %} I get the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /thank_you/
Could not parse the remainder: '‘thank_you.views.detail' from '‘thank_you.views.detail'. The syntax of 'url' changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.
```

I am completely stuck on this, please can somebody help? I will include as much of my code as I can.

mysite/settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '13k@ki=_o)(e$&8015fs4y#q=!3==92$6^dzn(iuu_h4&n6&d)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'thank_you',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
} 

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^thank_you/', include('thank_you.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

thank_you/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class ThankYou(models.Model):
    MODERATION_STATUS = (
        ('unmoderated', 'Unmoderated'),
        ('accepted', 'Accepted'),
        ('rejected', 'Rejected'),
    )
    mod_status = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=MODERATION_STATUS, default='unmoderated')

    your_name = models.CharField('Senders Name', max_length=50)
    fb_rec = models.CharField('Recipients Name', max_length=50)
    rec_dep = models.CharField('Recipients Department',max_length=100)
    ty_reason = models.CharField('Reason for sending', max_length=200)
    fb_anon = models.BooleanField('Anonymous?', default=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Published', auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.mod_status
```

thank_you/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from thank_you import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'thank_you.views.index'),
        url(r'^(?P<thank_you_id>\d+)/$', 'thank_you.views.detail'),
        url(r'^new_ty_form/$', 'thank_you.views.new_ty_form'),
)
```

thank_you/views.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from thank_you.models import ThankYou
from thank_you.forms import NewTYForm

def index(request):
   latest_ty_list = ThankYou.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
   context = {'latest_ty_list': latest_ty_list}
   return render(request, 'thank_you/index.html', context)

def detail(request, thank_you_id):
   ty = get_object_or_404(ThankYou, pk=thank_you_id)
   return render(request, 'thank_you/detail.html', {'ty': ty})

def new_ty_form(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = NewTYForm(request.POST)
        form.save(commit=True)
        return redirect('thank_you.views.index')
    else:
        form = NewTYForm()
        return render_to_response('thank_you/new_ty_form.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

thank_you/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from thank_you.models import ThankYou

class NewTYForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ThankYou
        fields = ('your_name', 'fb_rec', 'rec_dep', 'ty_reason', 'fb_anon')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Thank You!</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% if latest_ty_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for ty in latest_ty_list %}
        {% if ty.fb_anon %}
            <li><a href=“{% url ‘thank_you.views.detail ty.id %}”>Anonymous</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href={{ ty.id }}>{{ ty.your_name }}</a></li>             
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No thank yous are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <a href=new_ty_form/>Add a new thank you</a>
</body>

</html>
```

detail.html

```
<h1>{{ ty.id }}</h1>
{% if ty.fb_anon %}
<h1>Anonymous</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>{{ ty.your_name }}</h1>
{% endif %}
<h1>{{ ty.fb_rec }}</h1>
<h1>{{ ty.rec_dep }}</h1>
<h1>{{ ty.ty_reason }}</h1>
<h1>{{ ty.pub_date }}</h1>
```

new_ty_form.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>New Thank You</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Thank You</h1>

<form id=“new_ty_form” method=“post” action=“/thank_you/new_ty_form/“>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </table>
    <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the code overload, I just have a feeling that i'm missing something small and I can't find it. i've scoured the Django docs and tutorials but no luck.

Comment: You have curly quotes throughout. `“` and `‘` are not the same as `"` and `'`. Please don't use a word processor to write code; use a text editor. Plus, you're missing a close quote on that URL line in index.html.

Comment: I have been using textedit on my mac. I have set it up to edit in unformatted text.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much @DanielRoseman! My textedit was automatically editing my " and ' to the word processor forms in my .html files. If I hold control it types the correct form. and now my code works, thank you very much for helping me out :)